# Codeigniter Routing with HMVC not working

Tags: codeigniter, routes, hmvc, codeigniter-hmvc

I'm using Codeigniter with HMVC, I Have a sub controller with a name differed from Module name

---

```
- modules
      - manage
        - controllers
          - manage.php
        - views
          - dashboard.php

      - properties
         - controllers
            - properties.php
            - manage.php
         - views
            - properties.php
            - manage.php
      - projects 
        - controllers
          - projects.php
          - manage.php
        - views
          - projects.php
          - manage.php
```

if the url like this (index only working)

`sitename.com/manage/proprties`

this working fine, but if I passed some parameters,( Error 404)
`sitename.com/manage/properties/add`

OR

`sitename.com/manage/properties/edit/10`

My Routing like this

```
$route['manage/(:any)']                     ="$1/manage";
$route['manage/(:any)/(:any)']              ="$1/manage/$2";
$route['manage/(:any)/(:any)/(:num)']       ="$1/manage/$2/$3";
```

How to make URL `sitename.com/manage/properties/edit/10` working?

Answer (score 0):

In routes you have wrong. Depending on your version of codeigniter.

https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc

**Examples:**

```
$route['default_controller'] =" folder/controller/index"; // Only works codeigniter 2 so far codeigniter 3 will not allow is bug in codeigniter 3

$route['name'] =" folder/controller/index"; // Example

$route['manage'] =" manage/manage/index";

$route['manage/add'] =" manage/manage/add"; 

$route['manage/update/(:any)'] =" manage/manage/update/$1"; // (:any) sbsu2783
$route['manage/update/(:num)'] =" manage/manage/update/$1"; // (:num) 2783
$route['manage/update/(:any)/(:any)'] =" manage/manage/update/$1/$2"; // Just example

$route['manage/delete'] =" manage/manage/delete";

$route['manage/(:any)'] =" manage/manage/index/$1/$2"; // Not need most of the time
```

sitename.com/manage/edit/10

You may need to include the index.php or may not as not sure if you have configured your htaccess.

For example on controller `site_url('manage/update') .'/'. $this->uri->segment(4);`

Comment: my Codeigniter version is `2.1.3` , Using your suggestion, I have to add Routing for each Method,  Is this what you mean?

Comment: Yes you need to set routes for each controller some times you will not need the updates `$route['name'] =" folder/controller/function";` is the general way you should use 2.2.1 download from http://www.codeigniter.com/

Comment: but I need to build a way to auto routing modules, many developers build modules using my project ... any another solutions for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using HMVC then for calling function of Inner Controller does not require any routing. Just configure it correctly.

Second.  name of your module and controller both are same. so when 
you call 
**localhost/manage**  it redirects it to **manage/manage/index** by default  but  when you call 
**localhost/manage/update**   it try to find controller named update. so call like this
**localhost/manage/manage/update**